# Get elements to add up in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, math, csv

I have the following code -

```
private static void convert()
{                 
  webservice.Sum[] test = new webservice.Sum[1];         
  webservice.feed CallWebService = new webservice.feed();          
  foreach(XElement el in turnip.Descendants("row"))         
    {             
    test[0].person = el.Descendants("var").Where
         (
         x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == "person"
         ).SingleOrDefault().Attribute("value").Value;

    test[0].time = System.Convert.ToInt32(el.Descendants("var").Where
         (
          x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == "time"
         ).SingleOrDefault().Attribute("value").Value);

    test[0].erase = System.Convert.ToInt32(el.Descendants("var").Where
         (
          x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == "erase"
          ).SingleOrDefault().Attribute("value").Value);

    test[0]. available = el.Descendants("var").Where
         (
          x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == "available"
          ).SingleOrDefault().Attribute("value").Value;             

    test[0].external = el.Descendants("var").Where
         (
          x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == "external"
          ).SingleOrDefault().Attribute("value").Value;    
    CallWebService.updateFeed(test, year);
      } 
}
```

What I need to do is to get the 'person' and 'time' elements in the test array to add up seperately. For instance they are getting read in from a csv, so if the csv had account with the values of , 10, 20 and 30. I would want it to show account as having the desired value of 60. Then the same with erase. These would be the desired values to be presented in the form when run, then the person values would be returned from the web service, if it came back 40 for account and not 60, that would show an error occuring.

To make it clear right now I am getting a response from the web service, however it will not always be the desired value returned. The reulst from the webservice are returned on a web form, I want to have the results from the web service on the form (which I have) and what the results should definately be to compare or confirm the reults are correct. So on run time the form will tell me what the added up values of account are from the csv, then what the web service results have returned.

Comment: Please format your code!!!

Comment: Please correct your code and add some newlines. It's not readable.

Comment: please format the code in a more readable way. It is very hard to read anything there.

Comment: sorry folks had a bit of a nightmare there!

Comment: What is the question here?  What you have written so far doesn't really make any sense.  Please provide a sample input, and the output you need for that input.

Comment: I have edited hopefully that is more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like i got your problem via Chat i try to solve your problem.

This is if you want to get the sum of the whole CSV:

```
private int SumOfCSV(string filePath)
{
        string csvContent = String.Empty;
        int returnValue = 0;

        try
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
            csvContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();

            foreach(string value in csvContent.Split(';'))
            {
                returnValue += Convert.ToInt32(value);

            }               

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Reading " + Path.GetFileName(filePath) + " Failed.");
        }

        return returnValue;
}
```

Alex